# How to create a two foreign key relation in Objection.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, objection.js

Is there any way to create a two foreign key relation in Objection.js. Something like following:

```
  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      childs: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: childModel,
        join: {
          from: 'parent.id',
          to: 'child.parent_id'
        },
        join: { // Another foreign key
          from: 'parent.record_id',
          to: 'child.parent_record_id'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found out the solution at [docs](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/composite-keys.html#examples)

```
  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      childs: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: childModel,
        join: {
          from: [
            'parent.id',
            'parent.record_id'
          ],
          to: [
            'child.parent_id',
            'child.parent_record_id'
          ]
        },
      }
    }
  }
```